# create connection string in application page so as to connect with SQL server databse

Tags: database-connection

I have a SharePoint 2013 application where I want to display some of the data from SQL table on my page. I have created a connection string which is:

```
string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SharePointFBA"].ConnectionString;
```

Now when I write `cnn.open()` to open the connection it says "string doesn't contain a definition for 'open' and no extension method for open.

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like below.

```
string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SharePointFBA"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(cnn))
{
   conn2.open();
}
```

Please ask SharePoint related question only in this community.

Comment: Happy to help you...